# Looking for QML scrollBar component

Tags: qt, scrollbar, qml

Who knows QML scrollbar component with the standard Windows style?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the blog entry [QML Components for Desktop?](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/03/10/qml-components-for-desktop/) in the Qt Labs Blog. But beware: this is unfinished code and in my installation (Qt 4.7.2, Vista, MSVC-2008) the example did not work out of the box for me.

Comment: The link is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't need this anymore, but I just stumbled into the same problem and [this post](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/15283/) might be useful to whoever have the same needs. It contains a scrollbar qml source that worked pretty well for me. It doesn't have the standard windows style though, so you'd have to tweak its appearance a little.

Comment: If you really really want to match the desktop's scrollbar, you'd have to make several skins for XP, Vista, 7, 8, Mac OSX, etc. Not hard to do, but time consuming.